# Using do loops in sas

Tags: sas

Assume you have a data file called VIRUS_PROLIF from an infectious disease research center.  Each observation has 3 variables COUNTRY START_DATE, and DOUBLE_RATE, where START_DATE is the date that the Country registered its 100th case of COVID-19.  For each country, DOUBLE_RATE is the number of days it takes for the number of cases to double in that country.  Write the SAS code using DO UNTIL to calculate the date at which that Country would be predicted to register 200,000 cases of COVID-19.

```
  data VIRUS_PROLIF;
INPUT COUNTRY $ start_date mmddyy10. num_of_cases double_rate ;
*here doubling rate is 100% so if day 1 had 100 cases day 2 will have 200;
 Datalines;
 US 03/13/2020 100 100
  ;
 run;

data VIRUS_PROLIF1 (drop=start_date);
set VIRUS_PROLIF;
 do until (num_of_cases>200000);
double_rate+1;
num_of_cases+ (num_of_cases*1);
end;
 run;
 proc print data=VIRUS_PROLIF1;
 run;
```

Comment: Is there a question ?

Comment: Add comments to your code so its clear what you think each line does. You may also want to add an OUTPUT statement so you can se it. I would recommend working out this case in Excel first, figuring out the logic and then programming it. In this case your program is mostly correct, it's your logic for counting days that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The key concept you're missing here is how to employ the growth rate. That would be using the following formula, similar to interest growth for money.

If you have one dollar today and you get 100% interest it becomes
`StartingAmount * (1 + interestRate)` where the interest rate here is 100/100 = 1.

```
*fake data;

data VIRUS_PROLIF;
    INPUT COUNTRY $ start_date mmddyy10. num_of_cases double_rate;
    *here doubling rate is 100% so if day 1 had 100 cases day 2 will have 200;
    Datalines;
US 03/13/2020 100 100
AB 03/17/2020 100 20
;
run;

data VIRUS_PROLIF1;
    set VIRUS_PROLIF;
    *assign date to starting date so both are in output;
    date=start_date;
    *save record to data set;
    output;

    do until (num_of_cases>200000);
        *increment your day;
        date=date+1;
        ;
        *doubling rate is represented as a percent so add it to 1 to show the rate;
        num_of_cases=num_of_cases*(1+double_rate/100);
        *save record to data set;
        output;
    end;
    *control date display;
    format date start_date date9.;
run;

*check results;

proc print data=VIRUS_PROLIF1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem *200,000 < N<sub>0</sub> (1+R/100) <sup>k</sup>* can be solved for integer **k** without iterations

```
   day_of_200K = ceil ( 
        LOG ( 200000 / NUM_OF_CASES ) 
      / LOG ( 1 + R / 100 ) 
    );
```